# concrete5 Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, concrete5

This aray echos custom atribute for 'subscription-end'. This echos a date set.
Where am i going wrong?

```
<?php
$u = new User();
if($u->isLoggedIn()) {
$ui = UserInfo::getByID($u->getUserID());
echo $ui->getAttribute('subscription_end');
foreach ($valeus as $date) {
echo $date ('l d F Y  ');
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the variable $date as a function, that's why you get the error about an undefined function.

```
echo date ('l d F Y  ', $date);
```

is correct if your dates are in unix timestamp format.

Comment: Inserting this returns:  2014-10-02 00:00:00Thursday 01 January 1970

Comment: As I wrote: it is correct if your dates are in unix timestamp format.

Comment: Sorry for that. Think in other string it runs as $mask. This is how i display actual time: <?php $date = Loader::helper("date"); echo $date->getLocalDateTime('now',$mask = 'l d F Y ')?>